# Is "to which" used correctly in my sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I made a trip to Stanford University and wrote this sentence in my research paper:

> Moreover, across The Thinker’s exhibit is The Three Shades that is related to which in The Gates of Hell which is Rodin's massive work of group sculpture."

"To which" in this case refers to The Thinker which I mentioned early in my sentence. I just want to ask is my "to which" used incorrectly in this sentence?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: I guess the intended sense is along the lines of "Moreover, across from the exhibit of *The Thinker* is the related piece *The Three Shades* in *The Gates of Hell,* Rodin's massive work of group sculpture." Did I understand the meaning correctly, duyxp?

Comment: I'm guessing based on context that what you mean to say is something like "*The Three Shades, [note the comma] **which** [to denote that the prior clause is independent] is **alluded** to in The Gates of Hell, Rodin's massive work of group sculpture.*"  But to be sure, we'd need more context.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. In my paper, I wrote: "The first object I saw at the museum was The Thinker. It was the largest sculpture in the European section. Moreover, across The Thinker’s exhibit is The Three Shades that is related to which in The Gates of Hell which is Rodin's massive work of group sculpture." There you go.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, you did.

Comment: I concur with C.M. Weimer: the sentence is definitely NOT correct. Its intended meaning is not discernible to me.  If sumelic is correct, you have two pronouns in the same clause referring to the same antecedent (*that* and *which*), which is one too many.

Comment: @Hellion: the "which" is meant to refer to "The Thinker," but it's not grammatical either way.

Comment: Actually there are three separate items involved here: The Thinker, The Three Shades, and the Gates of Hell. Thus: "Moreover, across from The Thinker exhibit is The Three Shades, which is related to The Gates of Hell, Rodin's massive work of group sculpture."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Moreover, across The Thinker’s exhibit is The Three Shades that is related to which in The Gates of Hell which is Rodin's massive work of group sculpture.

The grammar of this is not correct, and as the comments indicate, the "to which" here is pretty much incomprehensible without the additional background information you provided in your question (that " 'To which' in this case refers to The Thinker which I mentioned early in my sentence").

The part of your sentence reading "that is related to which" seems to be an attempt at a "relative clause" that gives more information about *The Three Shades.*

In standard English, a relative clause is often introduced by a special word or phrase: the relativizer *that,* or a relative pronoun like *who* or *which,* or a phrase containing a relative pronoun like *of which* or *to which.*

Important points:

- There should only be one relative word or phrase, and it should come at the start of the relative clause. You used two relative words, "that" and "which," and the phrase "to which" was not placed at the start of the relative clause.
- The relative word refers back to the modified noun phrase. It cannot refer further back to an earlier noun phrase. This means you cannot use "to which" to refer to "The Thinker" when the "to which" is in a relative clause after "The Three Shades".

Here is an example of how to use "to which" correctly:

> *The Three Shades* should be interpreted in the context of *The Gates of Hell,* the group sculture **to which it belongs.**

The relative clause is "to which it belongs." It means the same thing as "that it belongs to." The relative clause modifies the noun phrase "the group sculture", which means the "which" in "to which" must refer to the group sculpture. The meaning is "It [*The Three Shades*] belongs to ***the group sculture*** [*The Gates of Hell*]."

If you want to put a relative clause after "The Three Shades" with a word referring back to *The Thinker,* you cannot use "which" as this word. You need to use the pronoun "it". The following sentence would be at least grammatical, although not very good stylistically:

> Moreover, across from *The Thinker*’s exhibit is *The Three Shades,* which is related **to it**, in *The Gates of Hell,* which is Rodin's massive work of group sculpture."

I have set off the relative clauses with commas because they are not "restrictive", but that's a different topic.

I think you don't need to use so many relative clauses, however. The words "which is" can often be dropped, and the relative clause "which is related to it" can be replaced by the words "the related piece" placed before "The Three Shades." This gives

> Moreover, across from *The Thinker*’s exhibit is the related piece *The Three Shades* in *The Gates of Hell,* Rodin's massive work of group sculpture.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. I saw my mistake after your first response. But this is too helpful. Thanks a lot guys for your attempts C. M. Weimer Hellion RaceYouAnytime.

Comment: @duyxp if this answers your question, feel free to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark next to it.